# Prevent absolutely positioned child from expanding scrollable area

Tags: html, css

I have a fixed size, scrollable parent div containing two children: The first contains the content, and should determine the size of the scrollable area. The second is small overlay that is moved around dynamically, and should *not* affect the size of the scrollable area. That is, if the overlay overhangs the bottom edge of the content, and the user scrolls all the way down (assuming the content is larger than the parent div), scrolling should stop once they hit the bottom of the content, even if that means only part of the overlay is visible.

Is this possible to achieve?

E.g., with this HTML:

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="content">
    <img src="640x423_image.jpg">
  </div>
  <div id="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

and this CSS:

```css
#parent {
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#overlay {
  position: absolute;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  top: 413px;
  left: 15px;
}
```

([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jmrowhx1/)), the browser lets the user scroll past the bottom of the content until the entire overlay (the blue square) is visible, while I would like it to stop once the bottom of the image is visible, leaving the bottom 50% of the overlay still hidden.

For my use case, I am able to make adjustments to the HTML if necessary.

Comment: Could you set bottom: 0; in the overlay class, and remove the top:413px; definition?

Comment: what will be the use of the overlay? and why it's there? can you give a more complete use case, probably the solution is to do this differently

Comment: It's a user controllable pointer that can be placed by the user. When placed near the bottom or right of the image, the part that hangs off the edge needs to be cut off (like when a mouse cursor reaches the edge of the screen), rather than expanding the scrollable area.

Comment: To clarify, if the content is smaller than the parent div, it's okay if some of the overlay appears outside of the content, but in no case should the parent div be able to be scrolled farther than it would be able to without the overlay present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put square box and img inside same container (`#content` in your case), and set `overflow: hidden;` on it.

```css
#parent {
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#content {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

#overlay {
  position: absolute;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  top: 413px;
  left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="content">
    <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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">
    <div id="overlay"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```